# Is there a way to write just a byte in BLE characteristic?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to android. My BLE device expects only one byte(flag). I tried writing only one byte in a byte array but it never works. While writing an array to another characteristic where it expects 2 bytes works. Is there a way to solve my problem or do I have to ask for device code to be changed?

I am working with [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-communicate-with-a-custom-ble-using-an-android-app/) project as my example

```
public void writeCustomCharacteristicStart() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        /*check if the service is available on the device*/
        BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("00001813-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        if(mCustomService == null){
            Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
            return;
        }
        /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
        byte pom= 1;
        byte[] data= new byte[1];
        data[0]=pom;
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a4e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

        if((mWriteCharacteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE)>0 ) {
            Log.w(TAG,"Writing started");
            mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(data)
        }
        if(!mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic)){
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
        }
        Log.w(TAG,"Writing ending");
    }
```

```
08-06 11:59:57.700 29279-29279/com.example.devicescanactivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.devicescanactivity, PID: 29279
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4084)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4858)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20167)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5931)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4079)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4858) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20167) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5931) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782) 
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10097 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1549)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1502)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.writeCharacteristic(IBluetoothGatt.java:1003)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt.java:1029)
        at com.example.devicescanactivity.BluetoothLeService.writeCustomCharacteristic(BluetoothLeService.java:377)
        at com.example.devicescanactivity.DeviceControlActivity.onClickWrite(DeviceControlActivity.java:332)
```

Here is the error, I don't get the BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED error, but I don't get any errors when I write to the characteristic that accepts 2 bytes.

Comment: Could you include the code where you write your byte in the question?

Comment: @zanerock is right, you should post your code so we can see what's going on. Otherwise it's difficult to help debug with you. You might just be doing some little thing wrong. And with that, I do know this is possible and that you don't need to change device code.

Comment: And if it errors out, post the error too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't in what I write in the characteristic it was what characteristic I used. I used HID Control Point which when tested on the computer nRF Connect app worked fine for my device but it would not work on android because of its predefined states. We just changed characteristic to Record Access Control Point and it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

First, to use bluetooth in your app, you need to add the following permissions to your app manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

It is possible to write a 1 byte value to a BLE characteristic, provided the device expects a 1 byte value.

If there is a length issue, you should see the error in the onCharacteristicWrite() callback:

```
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.i("TAG", "onCharacteristicWrite() status: " + status + "  - UUID: " + characteristic.getUuid());
        } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_LENGTH)  {
            Log.e("TAG", "onCharacteristicWrite() A write operation failed due to invalid attribute length");
        } else {
            Log.e("TAG", "onCharacteristicWrite() A write operation failed. Status = " + status);
        }
}
```

Also, I would move the writeCharacteristic() call inside your check for PROPERTY_WRITE to ensure the write operation can be done:

```
if((mWriteCharacteristic.getProperties() & BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0 ) {
    Log.i(TAG,"Writing started");
    mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(data)
    if(!mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic)){
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The device expects a byte but I only know how to send byte array.

Comment: Send a 1 byte array then. What log do you see in the onCharacteristicWrite() callback ? For info, When writing BLE characteristic, we write byte array. Look at Android's BluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue() which expects a byte array as paramater.

Comment: It errors out before writing, specifically on writeCharacteristic. Whole app restarts

Comment: Have you added the permissions to your manifest, as pointed out in my answer ?

Comment: That permission can only be added for system privileged apps.

Comment: I don't know how to get stack trace because my app restarts and starts scanning again which ruins my logcat.

Comment: In the filter at the top of logcat, have you selected to see log from your app only and Error only ?

Comment: Yea, but it resets immediately. Error message that I posted above I got by picking no filters and searching for it.

Comment: It seems your app does need the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and/or BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission. Please add them and try again